# flatten snowflake arrays into rows

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a snowflake table with 3 arrays (contained in one table row):

order array:

```
[
  1466369,
  1466369,
  1466369,
  1466369,
  1466369,
  1466369,
  1466369
]
```

part array

```
[
  17083,
  40052,
  173810,
  71874,
  104769,
  121607,
  47652
]
```

price array:

```
[
  9000.72,
  9920.5,
  11302.86,
  18458.7,
  26606.4,
  27686.2,
  36791.95
]
```

How can i convert the arrays into rows, so that each row is composed of 3 columns, so that the **first** row is comprised of 3 columns, made up of the first cell from each array,  and **second** row is comprised of the 3 columns - from the second cell  from each array , etc..... so that the conversion result will be 7 table rows (matching the 7 cells in each array).

the **flatten** keyword to break array cells into rows, eludes me.

Comment: The flatten keyword eludes you, you say? No surprise. Just look at this amaaaazing documentation: "FLATTEN is a table function that takes an ARRAY column and produces a lateral view. The lateral view is an inline view that contains correlation referring to other tables that precede it in the FROM clause." What trash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using  tally table to access array elements:

Data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t
AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON('[1466369, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369]') AS orders,
PARSE_JSON ('[17083, 40052, 173810, 71874, 104769, 121607,  47652]') AS part,
PARSE_JSON ('[9000.72, 9920.5, 11302.86, 18458.7, 26606.4,  27686.2, 36791.95]') AS price;
```

Query:

```
SELECT  orders[s.t]::INT AS orders, part[s.t]::INT AS part, price[s.t] AS price
FROM t
LEFT JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) AS s(t)
  ON s.t < GREATEST(ARRAY_SIZE(t.orders), ARRAY_SIZE(t.part), ARRAY_SIZE(t.price));
```

Output:

[image]

---

Alternatively:

```
SELECT  s1.index, s1.value, s2.value, s3.value
FROM t
,TABLE(FLATTEN(t.orders)) s1
,TABLE(FLATTEN(t.part)) s2
,TABLE(FLATTEN(t.price)) s3
WHERE s1.INDEX = s2.INDEX
  AND s2.INDEX = s3.INDEX;
```

Output:

[image]

Though this approach will explode really fast size_array_1 * size_array_2 * size_array_3.

---

EDIT:

> *I tried placing a value of null (undefined) in one of the arrays values, and when i do - the query would not return the row with null as one of the column values (returned 6 rows instead of 7) . is there away to address this*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t
AS
SELECT PARSE_JSON('[1466369, null, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369, 1466369]') AS orders,
PARSE_JSON ('[17083, 40052, 173810, 71874, 104769, 121607,  47652]') AS part,
PARSE_JSON ('[9000.72, 9920.5, 11302.86, 18458.7, 26606.4,  27686.2,36791.95]') AS price;
```

Query:

```
SELECT  s1.index, s1.value, s2.value, s3.value
FROM t
,TABLE(FLATTEN(t.orders, OUTER=> TRUE)) s1
,TABLE(FLATTEN(t.part, OUTER=> TRUE)) s2
,TABLE(FLATTEN(t.price, OUTER=> TRUE)) s3
WHERE s1.INDEX = s2.INDEX
  AND s2.INDEX = s3.INDEX;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: in the last query (after "alternatively...")-  when you reference s1, s2, s3  in the "FROM" section - does "flatten" know that "orders","part" and "price" are  columns in table t  ,  or is something missing ?

Comment: @Dror There is single table t so it does not requrie to have the table alias but you could add it.

Comment: thanks.
I tried placing a value of null (undefined) in one of the arrays values, and when i do - the query  would not return  the row with null as one of the column values (returned 6 rows instead of 7) .  is there away to address this ?

Comment: @Dror if you add `OUTER => TRUE` to the `FLATTEN` statement, it will retain the NULL.

Comment: @MikeWalton   i placed   'OUTER => TRUE'  in all  FLATTEN() clauses of the last query,  and still ending up with only 6 rows instead of 7

Comment: It seems that undefined is removed from output: `SELECT * FROM TABLE(FLATTEN(input=>PARSE_JSON('[1,undefined]'), OUTER=>TRUE)) s;` single row instead of two. Could you use `null` isntead of undefined?

Comment: @Dror The version with index works for both null/undefined.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda  interestingly, with null  the query indeed works ( returns 7 rows), but with undefined the query doesn't work (returns only 6 rows) -  i used the exact SQL that was pasted in the answer, and replaced null with undefined.  one works, the other doesnt